# How to modify multicolumn at pages?

Tags: tables, tabularx, columns, multicolumn

Here is my code;

```
\begin{multicols}{3}[Yale University]
    \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{4cm}}
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}{
            \includegraphics[scale=2]{pic/altonji.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Joseph~Altonji}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Yale}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/judith-chevalier}{
            \includegraphics[scale=2]{pic/chevalier.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/judith-chevalier}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Judith~Chevalier}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Yale}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/judith-chevalier}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/ray-fair}{
            \includegraphics[scale=.48]{pic/fair.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/ray-fair}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Ray~Fair}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Yale}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/ray-fair}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\     
    \end{tabular}

\columnbreak

    \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{4cm}}
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/pinelopi-goldberg}{
            \includegraphics[scale=.5]{pic/goldberg.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/pinelopi-goldberg}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Pinelopi~Goldberg}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Yale}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/pinelopi-goldberg}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/william-nordhaus}{
            \includegraphics[scale=.5]{pic/nordhaus.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/william-nordhaus}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{William~Nordhaus}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Yale}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/william-nordhaus}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/larry-samuelson}{
            \includegraphics[scale=3.1]{pic/samuelson.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/larry-samuelson}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Larry~Samuelson}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Yale}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/larry-samuelson}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
    \end{tabular}   

\columnbreak

    \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{4cm}}
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/christopher-udry}{
            \includegraphics[scale=2]{pic/udry.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/christopher-udry}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Christopher~Udry}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Yale}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/christopher-udry}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
    \end{tabular}   
\end{multicols}

\begin{multicols}{3}[Berkeley University]
    \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{4cm}}
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/alan-auerbach}{
            \includegraphics[scale=2]{pic/auerbach.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/alan-auerbach}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Alan~Auerbach}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Berkeley}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/alan-auerbach}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/aaron-edlin}{
            \includegraphics[scale=2]{pic/edlin.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/aaron-edlin}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Aaron~Edlin}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Berkeley}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/aaron-edlin}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/barry-eichengreen}{
            \includegraphics[scale=2]{pic/eichengreen.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/barry-eichengreen}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Barry~Eichengreen}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Berkeley}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/barry-eichengreen}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
    \end{tabular}   

\columnbreak

    \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{4cm}}
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/hilary-hoynes}{
            \includegraphics[scale=1.2]{pic/hoynes.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/hilary-hoynes}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Hilary~Hoynes}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Berkeley}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/hilary-hoynes}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/maurice-obstfeld}{
            \includegraphics[scale=.5]{pic/obstfeld.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/maurice-obstfeld}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Maurice~Obstfeld}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Berkeley}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/maurice-obstfeld}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/emmanuel-saez}{
            \includegraphics[scale=2]{pic/saez.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/emmanuel-saez}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Emmanuel~Saez}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Berkeley}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/emmanuel-saez}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
    \end{tabular}   

\columnbreak

    \begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{4cm}}
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/carl-shapiro}{
            \includegraphics[scale=2]{pic/shapiro.png} } &
        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/carl-shapiro}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Carl~Shapiro}}

        {\color[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844} Berkeley}

        \href{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/carl-shapiro}{\textcolor[rgb]{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961}{Bio/Vote
                History}}\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{multicols}
```

Here is the results;

[image: The result]

As I have shown in the picture, I want to move columns in page 2 to page 1. I use \columnbreak, however, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- your images are to big that all can fit in one page, so always some of them will go to the next page.
- since you provide only code snippet i'm not willing to reconstruct you document settings from scratch. this i left to you
- your code is unnecessary complicated/unclear. in my *mwe* i help myself with defining new command, which make document typing much simpler

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,
            linkcolor={blue},%{0.47058824,0.06666667,0.14901961},
            breaklinks=true,
            ]{hyperref}

\newcommand{\member}[5]{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{\ }m{2cm}@{\ }m{4cm}@{\ }}
    \rowcolor{white}
    \href{#1}
         {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=1.1\linewidth]{#2} }
    &
    \href{#1}
         {#3}\newline
    \textcolor[rgb]{0.39607844,0.39607844,0.39607844}{#4}\newline
    \href{#1}
         {#5}
    \end{tabular}\vskip-1.1\baselineskip
                    }


\begin{document}
    \begin{multicols}{3}[Standford University]
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {example-image-a}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\end{multicols}

    \begin{multicols}{3}[Yale University]
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {example-image-a}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\end{multicols}

    \begin{multicols}{3}[Berkeley University]
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {example-image-a}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\member{http://www.igmchicago.org/participants/joseph-altonji}
        {pic/altonji.png}
        {Joseph~Altonji}
        {Yale}
        {Bio/Vote History}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]